# How to create read only and shared folders for multiple users SFTP?

Tags: linux, centos7, ftp, sftp

Using the steps mentioned in this [link](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-up-an-sftp-server-on-linux/)

I am able to setup a basic SFTP server and create 2 users customer1 and customer2.

And each will get their own root folders.

Is there anyway to create shared folders between them and with both read-only and read/write mode.

Please suggest.

Comment: I think you need to unix groups..Create a group that both users and create a directory that can be access by both users in that group.  https://kifarunix.com/restrict-sftp-user-access-to-specific-directories-in-linux/ has some great info for you to test.

Comment: Hi, I tried that,  but it is not showing any folders outside the homedirectory set to the user.even it has permissions

Comment: Maybe a bind mount of that directory inside the users' root folders?

Comment: Thank you this link is helpful for bind mounts. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount

And these for unmounts.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/156667/how-to-unmount-after-using-mount-bind-option
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878707/how-to-unmount-a-busy-device

Comment: I am trying to add a certificate also for this ssh. But we have the certificate in pfx format received from godaddy, CA root authority. How to use it here, most of the links I got is creating a pem self signed one. How to use this existing pfx one? Please suggest